# How do we get speech output in Android app development?

Tags: android, gps, text-to-speech

I am developing an android app which requires route guidance in a map in the form of speech as output. So basically, I need to guide a passenger from one location to another location using speech as output(just as a GPS). I have looked at text to speech article in the android resources. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not want to use the version linked in the Android dev resources?

Comment: I was talking abt this article http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html ..wanted to get an insight on how this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably some third party speech engines available, but the one built into the Android framework is really quite good.  The reference docs aren't great on showing how to get started, but one of the engineers wrote a [guide on the Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) that's worth a look.

You can also look at the [AccessibilityService in the "ApiDemos" app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/accessibility/index.html), which uses the built-in text-to-speech engine to speak to the user when they click on items in a ListView.